# Arrays of objects in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

So, I'm trying to declare classes in an array, but I'm not sure how to do it. Here is the code I have, but my declaring the classes is not working. I'm sure that my syntax is wrong, but what should I do?

```
class Menu{
  public:
    Menu(int j, int k){
      //some code
    }
};

Menu allMenus[2] = {
  (1, 7),
  (2, 9)
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
Menu allMenus[2] = {
  Menu(1,7),
  Menu(2,9)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For POD types (no constructor) you may use:

```
Menu items[] = { {1,7}, {2,9} ... };
```

But you have constructor so you must call it implicitly:

```
Menu items[] = { Menu(1,7), Menu(2,9) ... };
```